# Error with table mapping ASPNET Identity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, code-first

I am new to this obviously but ive been working with the new identity membership provider trying to convert our old site to a standard platform. Everything so far seems to be working as expected, but when i try to login to our site,i get the following error {"Invalid column name 'ApplicationUser_Id'."}. I believe this has to do with the way EF is trying to map the relationship between my two user tables. I have the first table AspNetUsers and then an extended profile table called ISF_ProfileEmployee. Please see the information below. I was following the blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/20/building-a-simple-todo-application-with-asp-net-identity-and-associating-users-with-todoes.aspx by pranav rastogi so if hes around the help would be greatly appreciated.

Heres my code.

```
    public class ISF_ProfileEmployee
    {

        public Guid UserID { get; set; }
        public string AlternateEmployeeId { get; set; }
        public Guid DefaultDashboardId { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public string AlternateEmailAddress { get; set; }
        public DateTime EmploymentStartDate { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeStatus { get; set; }
        public bool IsSupervisor { get; set; }
        public Guid ISFLocationId { get; set; }
        public Guid ISFDepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Guid ISFSupervisorId { get; set; }
        public Guid ISFPositionId { get; set; }
        public Guid StatusId { get; set; }
        public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
        public DateTime StatusUpdateDate { get; set; }
        public bool InBoardUser { get; set; }
        public Guid? InBoardStatus { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
        public string GersUserId { get; set; }
        public bool UseCustomDash { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Nickname { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool Disabled { get; set; }
        public DateTime? BirthDay {get; set;}
        public string ImageFileName {get; set;}
        public string OfficePhone {get; set;}
        public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
        public string Extension { get; set; }
        public string FaxPhone {get; set;}
        public string PasswordQuestion {get; set;}
        public string PasswordAnswer {get; set;}
        public DateTime CreateDate {get; set;}
        public DateTime LastLockoutDate {get; set;}
        public bool IsLockedOut {get; set;}
        public int FailedPasswordAttemptCount {get; set;}
        public DateTime FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart {get; set;}
        public int FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount {get; set;}
        public DateTime FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart {get; set;}
        public DateTime LastPasswordChangedDate {get; set;}
        public string Comment {get; set;}

        public ISF_ProfileEmployee ISF_ProfileEmployee { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasKey(k => k.Id).Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey(r=>r.Id).Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("RoleId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().Property(p => p.Name).HasColumnName("RoleName");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ISF_ProfileEmployee>().ToTable("ISF_ProfileEmployee").HasKey(p => p.UserID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasRequired(x => x.ISF_ProfileEmployee).WithRequiredPrincipal();

    }
```

Comment: I don't see the property ApplicationUser_Id anywhere in these classes. Is it being referenced in a view? The view may expect the model to have it and throw an error when it is not found

Comment: No its not being referenced anywhere. From what i can determine, the entity framework is attempting to resolve the mapping between the two tables and expecting a column with that name, when there isnt one.

Comment: have you done a solution search for `ApplicationUser_Id`

Comment: Yes, no matches were found.

Comment: foreign key on one of the tables perhaps?

Comment: No, the models for the tables were included above. THe tables in SQL server match the models exactly.

Comment: Well, for one, I'm not sure why you would want a separate table to store additional user information. Just put it all on the same `ApplicationUser` or use claims.

Comment: This database is used for multiple applications. The AspNetUsers table is common to all users, ISF_ProfileEmployee is not necessarily

Answer (score 1):

I never could get a answer to solve this problem. The Identity Membership is apparently very picky about the column names in the tables you use. I ended up merging my two tables and changing the UserId column back to Id(which is the name that Aspnet Identity expects) once i did this, i was able to move forward pretty easily. In my opinon a lot more work needs to be done on the ability to customize the schema that it uses. Also the lack of documentation is quite frustrating, the idea is great, but the follow through leaves something to be desired.

Answer (score 0):

I think what might be happening is that since you were migrating from earlier membership system which had an ApplicationUserId column, either the column is still there or EF is looking for that column and is failing to map the column. Try mapping the ApplicationUserId column to UserId and see if that works

Comment: That column is not available on either of my models when i attempt to use modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.

Comment: Did you have any other thoughts on resolving this?